# #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 100000 equivalent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

What is the Swift syntax for:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 100000
//...
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct analog of the `#if` compile-time directive for max OS version, but depending upon the broader objective, there are a few techniques you can avail yourself of:

1. There is a `#if` directive in Swift for language version (but not OS versions). See "Conditional Compilation Block" section of [The Swift Programming Language: Language Reference: Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID428). For example:

   ```
   #if swift(>=3.0)
   func foo(with array: [Any]) {
       print("Swift 3 implementation")
   }
   #else
   func foo(with array: [AnyObject]) {
       print("Swift 2 implementation")
   }
   #endif
   ```
2. You can perform `#available` *runtime* check for OS versions. See "Checking API Availability section of [The Swift Programming Language: Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120). For example, UserNotifications framework is available effective iOS 10, so you'd do something like:

   ```
   private func registerForLocalNotifications() {
       if #available(iOS 10, *) {
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
               guard granted && error == nil else {
                   // display error
                   print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                   return
               }
           }
       } else {
           let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.badge, .sound, .alert]
           let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
           UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you have an API that is only available in certain OS versions, you can use `@available` directive. See "Declaration Attributes" discussion in [The Swift Programming Language: Language Reference: Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID347) for more information. For example:

   ```
   @available(iOS, introduced: 9.0, deprecated: 11.0)
   func someMethod() {
       // this is only supported iOS 9 and 10
   }
   ```

   or,

   ```
   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
   func someMethod() {
       // this is only available in iOS 10 and later
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for clear explanations! I used 2. for my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want conditional compile for the same swift version you can use for ex.

```
let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: URL(string: "https://my.com")!, callbackURLScheme: "") { (url, error) in }
#if compiler(>=5.1)
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    session.presentationContextProvider = self
}
#endif
```

Compile version can be found in `swift --version`